# Add points to pairs plot?

Tags: r, plot, coordinates

Is there any way for me to add some points to a `pairs` plot?

For example, I can plot the Iris dataset with `pairs(iris[1:4])`, but I wanted to execute a clustering method (for example, `kmeans`) over this dataset and plot its resulting centroids on the plot I already had.

It would help too if there's a way to plot the whole data and the centroids together in a single `pairs` plot in such a way that the centroids can be plotted in a different way. The idea is, I plot `pairs(rbind(iris[1:4],centers)` (where centers are the three centroids' data) but plotting the three last elements of this matrix in a different way, like changing cex or pch. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You give the solution yourself in the last paragraph of your question. Yes, you can use `pch` and `col` in the `pairs` function.

```
pairs(rbind(iris[1:4], kmeans(iris[1:4],3)$centers), 
      pch=rep(c(1,2), c(nrow(iris), 3)), 
      col=rep(c(1,2), c(nrow(iris), 3)))
```

Comment: I thought it could be solved that way, but I didn't know how to do it. thanks!
ps: iris is classified in 3 groups :P

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `panel` function:

```
cl <- kmeans(iris[1:4],3)
idx <- subset(expand.grid(x=1:4,y=1:4),x!=y)
i <- 1
pairs(iris[1:4],bg=cl$cluster,pch=21,
            panel=function(x, y,bg, ...) {
                points(x, y, pch=21,bg=bg)
                points(cl$center[,idx[i,'x']],cl$center[,idx[i,'y']],
                             cex=4,pch=10,col='blue')
                i <<- i +1
            })
```

[image]

But I think it is safer and easier to use `lattice splom` function. The legend is also automatically generated.

cl <- kmeans(iris[1:4],3)

```
library(lattice)
splom(iris[1:4],groups=cl$cluster,pch=21,
            panel=function(x, y,i,j,groups, ...) {
                panel.points(x, y, pch=21,col=groups)
                panel.points(cl$center[,j],cl$center[,i],
                             pch=10,col='blue')
            },auto.key=TRUE)
```

[image]